# I need to save the User Name and email address separately. I am am having an issue with logging into the site after the user is registered

Tags: asp.net-core, identity

I am creating a new ASP.NET Core (2.2) WebSite. By default, the UserName and Email Address is the same thing. I want to have them be different. The issue comes in when I try to log that user back into the web page.

I scaffolded the register Identity page and made some simple changes to the Code behind and also the Razor page itself (see below). I did also scaffold the login page, but I don't think that I need to make any changes there, because I am ok with folks logging in using their email address still.

Here are the edits to the Register.cshtml.cs page.

I added this to the InputModel class:

```
[Required]
[StringLength(256, ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be at least {2} and at max {1} characters long.", MinimumLength = 5)]
[DataType(DataType.Text)]
[Display(Name = "User Name")]
public string UserName { get; set; }
```

I also changed the user in the OnPostAsync method

```
var user = new IdentityUser { UserName = Input.UserName, Email = Input.Email };
```

Everything else is as default.

On the page itself, I simply added it below the email:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label asp-for="Input.UserName"></label>
    <input asp-for="Input.UserName" class="form-control"/>
    <span asp-validation-for="Input.UserName" class="text-danger"></span>
</div>
```

I would expect for the user to be logged in as normal, alas. The error I get is simply "Invalid Log-in attempt". Annoyingly, The user I created before making any changes still is able to be logged in just fine. So my gut tells me that Something is funny in the register page, I am just not sure where.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to modify `SignInManager.PasswordSignIn` method. By default it uses `FindByNameAsync` to check if user with given name exists , you should change to `FindByEmailAsync` .

1. Create new `SignInManager` :

   ```
   public class MySignInManager : SignInManager<IdentityUser>
   {
       public MySignInManager(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UserManager<Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityUser> userManager, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.IHttpContextAccessor contextAccessor, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IUserClaimsPrincipalFactory<Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityUser> claimsFactory, Microsoft.Extensions.Options.IOptions<Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityOptions> optionsAccessor, Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ILogger<Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.SignInManager<Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityUser>> logger, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.IAuthenticationSchemeProvider schemes)
           : base(userManager, contextAccessor, claimsFactory, optionsAccessor, logger, schemes)
       {
       }

       public override async Task<SignInResult> PasswordSignInAsync(string userName, string password,
           bool isPersistent, bool lockoutOnFailure)
       {
           var user = await UserManager.FindByEmailAsync(userName);
           if (user == null)
           {
               return SignInResult.Failed;
           }

           return await PasswordSignInAsync(user, password, isPersistent, lockoutOnFailure);
       }
   }
   ```
2. Register the `SignInManager`:

   ```
   services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>()
       .AddDefaultUI(UIFramework.Bootstrap4)
       .AddSignInManager<MySignInManager>()   //register new SignInManager 
       .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();
   ```

Comment: THANK YOU! This works like a charm. I added the above code verbatim and now everything works. I am so grateful.

Comment: @snussel , please mark my reply as answer by clicking the green check button which may help others who meet same problem

Comment: I just wanted to add that in my case I had to add another argument in the constructor:

`IUserConfirmation<IdentityUser> confirmation`