# ASP.NET Core : How to login with “UserName” instead of “Email”?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core

With asp.net core, all the login pages and viewmodels etc are hidden in referenced packages, so can't be directly changed. How do I allow login to still make use of usernames and not force the use of emails?

Answer (score 60, accepted):

The first step is to scaffold identity to your application :

[Scaffold Identity in ASP.NET Core projects](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/scaffold-identity?view=aspnetcore-2.2&tabs=visual-studio)

Then you could customize the `Register.cshtml`/`Register.cshtml.cs` and `Login.cshtml`/`Login.cshtml.cs` , update model and view , and change the logic in `OnPostAsync` function to fit your requirement .

To your requirement , you can follow the steps :

1. Scaffold identity into your project .
2. Modify the `Register.cshtml.cs` , add Username to  `InputModel` :

   ```
   [Required]
   [DataType(DataType.Text)]
   [Display(Name = "User Name")]
   public string UserName { get; set; }
   ```
3. Modify the `OnPostAsync` method :

   ```
   var user = new IdentityUser { UserName = Input.UserName, Email = Input.Email };
   ```
4. Update the `Register.cshtml` to include the UserName :

   ```
   <div class="form-group">
       <label asp-for="Input.UserName"></label>
       <input asp-for="Input.UserName" class="form-control"/>
       <span asp-validation-for="Input.UserName" class="text-danger"></span>
   </div>
   ```
5. Modify the `Login.cshtml.cs` , modify `InputModel` to replace Email with UserName :

   ```
   [Required]
   [DataType(DataType.Text)]
   [Display(Name = "User Name")]
   public string UserName { get; set; }
   ```
6. Modify the `Login.cshtml` :

   ```
   <div class="form-group">
       <label asp-for="Input.UserName"></label>
       <input asp-for="Input.UserName" class="form-control" />
       <span asp-validation-for="Input.UserName" class="text-danger"></span>
   </div>
   ```
7. Modify the `Login.cshtml.cs` `OnPostAsync` method to use Username instead of email :

   ```
   var result = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(Input.UserName, Input.Password, Input.RememberMe, lockoutOnFailure: true);
   ```

By default ASP.NET Identity uses `FindByNameAsync` to check if user with given name exists , so that you don't need to override `PasswordSignInAsync` function in `SignInManager` . If you want to login with email , your could click [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55620595/i-need-to-save-the-user-name-and-email-address-separately-i-am-am-having-an-iss/55626039#55626039) to update that .

Comment: Thank you. This was really helpful and appreciate you taking the time to set the full working example :)

Comment: You made it simple, thanks!

Comment: The `OnPostAsync` in  `Register.cshmtl.cs` has to be updated too. Also, make sure to remove the email from the `InputModel` otherwise the validation will fail on server side (due to the `[Required]` attribute).

Answer (score 4):

When using the excepted answer I also had to modify the following line in step three from `Input.Email` to `Input.UserName` on the latest ASP.NET Core template.

```
await _userStore.SetUserNameAsync(user, Input.UserName, CancellationToken.None);
```

Answer (score 3):

Please consider that:
When using the accepted answer, if you don't want your users to click stupid "Confirm email" button, you need to:

1. Change `AddDefaultIdentity` function in your `Program.cs` to `options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = false` (not default `true`).
2. Delete everything that is assosiated with email confirmation in `Register.cshtml.cs`

There is full, clear & working `Register.cshtml.cs` without any stupid email things.

```
#nullable disable

using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace PhotoSite.Areas.Identity.Pages.Account
{
    public class RegisterModel : PageModel
    {
        private readonly SignInManager<IdentityUser> _signInManager;
        private readonly UserManager<IdentityUser> _userManager;
        private readonly IUserStore<IdentityUser> _userStore;
        private readonly ILogger<RegisterModel> _logger;

        public RegisterModel(
            UserManager<IdentityUser> userManager,
            IUserStore<IdentityUser> userStore,
            SignInManager<IdentityUser> signInManager,
            ILogger<RegisterModel> logger)
        {
            _userManager = userManager;
            _userStore = userStore;
            _signInManager = signInManager;
            _logger = logger;
        }

        [BindProperty]
        public InputModel Input { get; set; }

        public string ReturnUrl { get; set; }

        public IList<AuthenticationScheme> ExternalLogins { get; set; }

        public class InputModel
        {
            [Required]
            [DataType(DataType.Text)]
            [Display(Name = "User Name")]
            public string UserName { get; set; }

            [Required]
            [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be at least {2} and at max {1} characters long.", MinimumLength = 6)]
            [DataType(DataType.Password)]
            [Display(Name = "Password")]
            public string Password { get; set; }

            [DataType(DataType.Password)]
            [Display(Name = "Confirm password")]
            [Compare("Password", ErrorMessage = "The password and confirmation password do not match.")]
            public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }
        }

        public async Task OnGetAsync(string returnUrl = null)
        {
            ReturnUrl = returnUrl;
            ExternalLogins = (await _signInManager.GetExternalAuthenticationSchemesAsync()).ToList();
        }

        public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync(string returnUrl = null)
        {
            returnUrl ??= Url.Content("~/");
            ExternalLogins = (await _signInManager.GetExternalAuthenticationSchemesAsync()).ToList();
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                var user = CreateUser();

                await _userStore.SetUserNameAsync(user, Input.UserName, CancellationToken.None);
                var result = await _userManager.CreateAsync(user, Input.Password);

                if (result.Succeeded)
                {
                    _logger.LogInformation("User created a new account with password.");
                    await _signInManager.SignInAsync(user, isPersistent: false);
                    return LocalRedirect(returnUrl);
                }
                foreach (var error in result.Errors)
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, error.Description);
                }
            }
            // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
            return Page();
        }

        private IdentityUser CreateUser()
        {
            try
            {
                return Activator.CreateInstance<IdentityUser>();
            }
            catch
            {
                throw new InvalidOperationException($"Can't create an instance of '{nameof(IdentityUser)}'. " +
                    $"Ensure that '{nameof(IdentityUser)}' is not an abstract class and has a parameterless constructor, or alternatively " +
                    $"override the register page in /Areas/Identity/Pages/Account/Register.cshtml");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Look inside Pages -> Login.cshtml page (Here, you will get a class named Login.cshtml.cs). Inside that class, you will get a method named 'OnPostAsync'

Change frontend as likes

[image]

And inside your 'Login.cshtml.cs' class change this method with your target Dashboard/Index url..

```
 public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync()
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var validated = _ADService.Validate(new NetworkCredential(LoginData.UserId, LoginData.Password));
            if (validated)
            {
                if (await _identityService.SignInAsync(HttpContext, LoginData.UserId))
                {

              //   return Redirect("Index");
                   return Redirect("../app/bootstrap.html");

                }

                ModelState.AddModelError("", "account does not exist in system!");
                return Page();
            }

            ModelState.AddModelError("", "userid or password is invalid!");
            return Page();
        }
        else
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("", "userid or password is blank!");
            return Page();
        }
    }
```

Comment: No, there is a LoginPartial in Views/Shared which contains the login button/user detail on the master page, but as I said in the question, the login pages and viewmodels are all propped up into the netcore dll's.

Comment: you have to scaffold out the Identity, I assume its in the areas -> identity, right click Add -> New Scaffolded Items -> Identity, Select all items you want scaffolded.  Modify as necessary